# Grouped Text classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, text-classification

I have thousands groups of paragraphs and I need to classify these paragraphs. The problem is that I need to classify each paragraph based on other paragraphs in the group! For example, a paragraph individually maybe belongs to class A but according to other paragraph in the group it belongs to class B.

I have tested lots of traditional and deep approaches( in fields like text classification, IR, text understanding, sentiment classification and so on) but those couldn't classify correctly.

I was wondering if anybody has worked in this area and could give me some suggestion. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

**Update 1:**

Actually we are looking for manual sentences/paragraph for some fields, so we first need to recognize if a sentence/paragraph is a manual or not second we need to classify it to it's fields and we can recognize its field only based on previous or next sentences/paragraphs.

To classify the paragraphs to manual/no-manual we have developed some promising approaches but the problem come up when we should recognize the field according to previous or next sentences/paragraphs, but which one?? we don't know the answer would be in any other sentences!!.

**Update 2:**

We can not use whole text of group as input because those are too big (sometimes tens of thousands of words) and contain some other classes and machine can't learn properly which lead to  the drop the accuracy sharply.

Here is a picture that maybe help to better understanding the problem:
[image]

Comment: Try to provide a [mcve]; also the problem's description can be more detailed.

Comment: Please expand on what the features are

Comment: I think this question rather belongs to [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) forum than here.